# Nuxtjs property or method not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get a counter to add 1 to a variable counter in a nuxtjs template. Not sure what is going on here:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>London Weather</h1>
      <div id="example-1">
        <button @click="test()">Add 1</button>
        <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data: {
    counter: 0
  },
  methods: {
    test: function(counter) {
      this.counter += 1
      console.log(counter)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

- Reference counter as `this.counter`
- `data` is a function which should return whatever data you need
- `test` doesn't need to take parameters as you are just changing the component's state rather than modifying some parameter you're passing in

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>London Weather</h1>
      <div id="example-1">
        <button @click="test">Add 1</button>
        <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    test: function() {
      this.counter += 1
      console.log(this.counter)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[See it live here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/x28xxxy8jw)

Comment: you don't need 'this' on the counter in the template but +1 from me on the other two points.

Comment: Ah good point, I'll change that now. I always get mixed up where to put `this.` and where to leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```html
<template>
  ...
  <button @click="test(1)">Add 1</button>
  ...
</template>

<script>
...
methods: {
  test(count) {
    this.counter += count;
    console.log(this.counter)
  }
}
...
```